# How can I read a binary file (xml style) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, binaryfiles, readfile

I am trying to read a binary file which contains data between Tags (xml style), and I using a page like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Load a File</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <input type="file" id="file">
    </main>  
    <script>
 function onfilechange(evt) {
    var selFile = evt.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
        var h3d =new Int8Array(e.target.result);
        console.log(h3d);
        console.log(enc.decode(h3d));
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(selFile);
}
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', onfilechange);
var enc = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And I get this result for the file (first Console.log):

```
Int8Array(1025) [9, 0, 0, 0, 8, 60, 77, 79, 68, 69, 76, 79, 62, 9, 0, 0, 0, 8, 60, 80, 79, 78, 84, 79, 83, 62, 10, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 65, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 36, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 36, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 36, 64, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 36, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 68, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 36, 64, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 67, 0, 0, 0, 0, …]
```

and second Console.log:

```
<MODEL>
 <POINTS>A$@$@$@B$@D@$@CN@D@$@DN@$@$@EN@$@>@FN@D@>@GD@$@I@HD@D@I@ 
 I$@$@I@J$@D@I@</POINTS>
 <FACES>ABCDADEGIIGHJAIJBHGEFFEDCJHFCB</FACES>
<SYSTEM></SYSTEM>
</MODEL>
```

How can i get the actual data stored in between the tags?
I Should be geting some points coordinates like:

```
<MODEL> 
   <POINTS>A,10,10,10; B,10,20,30; ...</POINTS>
   <FACES>1,A,B,C,D; 2,A,D,E,G,I;...  </FACES>
   <SYSTEM>...and some other stuff!</SYSTEM>
</MODEL>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe, _maybe_, you can use a `DOMParser` with type `text/xml`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser - Then you can approach this as a javascript style `documentFragment` and look into nodes there? But I am not seeing that data there, so maybe try reading it as a string and not a binary?

Comment: @StackSlave But a button uses a `click` event, and we can just read the files in the input regardless.

Comment: @somethinghere Thanks, I gonna look into DOMParser. I am not very skilled in javascript. The program which creates the file was written in Delphi and I am trying to create a Javascript application similar to the original one.

Comment: Good luck! It kind of looks like you are trying to import some 3D vertices files etc... If its a 3D model or something, maybe better to look into existing solutions to read certain file types? THREE.js came with a lot of those, could be a good place to start.

Comment: Yes, it is 3d, and yes, it is to be used with Three.js. But the data is custom made, not any standard 3d files. I know how it is written in Delphi, but need to be able to read those files for compatibility reasons.

Comment: I mean, there are some very bssic filetypes you could use if you just convert the data files into something more common... I promise you your custom format will come back to haunt you! Wooo~~õoo! :) Good luck though, let me know if that worked!

Comment: I've just edited the question in order to be more clear! thank you!

Comment: If they are just numbers there I don't see why the TAGS would be legible but the contents all garbled... That makes no sense to me. Do you have any way to provide an example file you are trying to load?

Comment: Yes, thanks. :)  here goes a link to the file: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiEism69IcEvhZw1-xyIjnjxpXmwxA?e=YUSPtT

Comment: I have a lot of experience parsing binary files in JavaScript and this one confuses me. How are you encoding the data that is in the POINTS and FACES tags? I don't see any commas or semicolons in there. I have been able to mostly parse this file but I can't get that data.

Comment: The file was created in a Delphi program using "filestream.write". In that context, The tags are strings and the coordinates for X,Y and Z for the points are "reals". The names of the points (A, B, C...) Are strings as well. I don't know much more about it! Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot going on here so let me see if I can explain.

First, what you are expecting as the output of this file is not the actual data in this file. If you are going to create a binary format you need to document it. For example - the points in this file are not separated by commas and semicolons, they are simply a single byte Ascii character followed by 3 - 8 byte numbers. As a note - the numbers used for the points are encoded in the opposite order of the rest of the file.

When you load a file from the OS you are getting the raw bytes of the file. Those bytes need to be converted into something usable and that is why there are APIs like `TextDecoder` and `FileReader`. `TextDecoder` is designed to take a file that was encode as a text file (UTF-8, UTF-16, etc...) and convert it to a JavaScript string. This is not a text file, it is binary so you can't use `TextDecoder`

The reason that you are seeing the output that you are is because when you display a binary file in a text editor (The console is a text editor) it display each byte as the corresponding Ascii character. That is why you are seeing all the garbled text - they are actually ascii characters. The text editor doesn't know that they are supposed to be 8 byte numbers.

So, basically there are no JavaScript APIs that will convert this binary file into text because it doesn't know how - it doesn't know what the bytes it is reading represent. It also doesn't know how many bytes to read at a time (1 for a UTF-8 character, 2 for a UTF-16 character or 4 for an integer). You need to parse this file manually which isn't as scary as it seems. Right now you are using an `Int8Array` which will work but you have to use Array indexing and you will have to use bit shifting to get the numbers. You should use `DataView` because it provides an API to read different types from the byte stream.

This is an example of how to parse this file.

```js
let position = 0;
let h3d;
function onfilechange(evt) {
    const selFile = evt.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
        h3d = new DataView(e.target.result);
        while (position < h3d.byteLength) {
            if (isOpenBracket(h3d.getUint8(position++))) {
                // we are looking to see if we are starting a closing tag
                // don't increment position here - we just want to peek
                if (isSlash(h3d.getUint8(position))) {
                    while (!isCloseBracket(h3d.getUint8(position++))) {
                        // we don't need the closing tag so we will skip over it
                        // just read forward to the closing braket
                        // after this completes the 'position' will be on the byte representing the closing tag
                    }
                    // go back to the outer while loop
                    continue;
                }
                let tag = readTag(h3d, position);
                switch (tag) {
                    case 'PONTOS':
                    case 'POINTS':
                        const points = readPoints();
                    case 'FACES':
                        const faces = readFaces();
                     
                    // add other tags you want to parse

                }
            }
        }
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(selFile);
}

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', onfilechange);

function readTag() {
    const tag = [];
    // start reading tag
    // read until we find the closing bracket
    // after this completes the 'position' will be on the byte representing the closing tag
    while (!isCloseBracket(val = h3d.getUint8(position++))) {
        tag.push(val);
    }
    return String.fromCodePoint(...tag);
}

function readPoints() {
    const points = {}; // or use a Map
    // do this until we hit the openning bracket of the closing tag
    while (!isOpenBracket(val = h3d.getUint8(position++))) {
    // the points are an upper case letter followed by 3 - 8 byte numbers
    // so if we hit an uppercase letter read the next 3 - 8 byte sequences as numbers
        if (isChar(val)) {
            let arr = [];
            // we need to read these number as LittleEndian because that is how they are in the file
            arr.push(h3d.getFloat64(position, true));
            position += 8;
            arr.push(h3d.getFloat64(position, true));
            position += 8;
            arr.push(h3d.getFloat64(position, true));
            position += 8;

            points[String.fromCodePoint(val)] = arr;
        }
    }
    return points;
}

function readFaces() {
    // don't know what to do here because I don't know what the format of this data is.
}
// these functions check Ascii values - no need to covert them to strings
function isWhitesapce(value) {
    return value === 32 ||
        value === 9 ||
        value === 10 ||
        value === 11 ||
        value === 12 ||
        value === 13
}

function isOpenBracket(value) {
    return value === 60;
}
function isCloseBracket(value) {
    return value === 62;
}
function isSlash(value) {
    return value === 47;
}
function isChar(value) {
// upper case letters
    return value >= 41 && value <= 90;
}
```

This is just quick and dirty. I would create a separate class that parses this file format.

A few things to note:

1. When using DataView you have to keep track of the position you are reading from. It doesn't move the pointer forward automatically.
2. In the `readPoints` function the endianness of the `getFloat64` is set to true to use Little Endian because the data for the points in the file are encoded backwards.

That should be enough to figure out how to parse the rest of the file. You just need to know what the data format in each tag is.

Comment: Thank you very, very much. I would not get anywhere close to the solution by my self. Thank you for the answer and the time to look into it and explain it to me what was going on! TKS. ;)

Comment: I just found out the structure of the file: the first 4 bytes are the length of the next information. So first thing in the file is the size of next tag <MODELO>, rigth after that comes another number, the size of next information, and this goes to the end of the file. Faces are 2 dimentional arrays of strings. Now i can figure out how to parse the file... Thanks again! Cheers

Comment: Putting the length of a section in is pretty standard for binary files. If you know the length of the data you don't have to parse the entire file up front, you can split it into sections by creating multiple DataView's and parse it on demand. The DataView constructor takes optional byteOffset and length parameters and since a DataView is just a view into an ArrayBuffer it doesn't create a copy of the buffer. A TrueType font and a PDF document are like this. I have written parsers for both by splitting the file up and reading the sections on demand.

Comment: Hi Andrew Alderson, now I am trying to do the other way around, transform my array of points into binary data. Please, if you can, have a look at this question to see if you can guide me on the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65971616/filesaver-js-how-to-write-a-blob-containing-binary-data